# How do I restore the comment body field I deleted from a content type?

Tags: comments

I deleted the comment body from the content type settings, and replaced it with  another field. When posting comments, I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$comment_body in function `comment_submit()` (line 2201 in file /modules/comment/comment.module).

Can this error be avoided?

It was needed to delete the field comment_body becase field permissions are inherited for all the content types and that is why another field was created and this one was deleted.

Comment: Yes, despite the comment body is a field that can be removed from the UI, the Comment module assume the field is always present.

Comment: Oh, it is a little bit confusing. Can it be fixed in any way?

Comment: Did you try making a field with same machine name and type?

Comment: In this case I need to delete the field comment_body becase field permissions are inherited for all the content types and that is why I created another field and deleted this one. Yes, if I add it back, it is restored but this action doesn't completely solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a random content type
- Restore the comment_body field from existing field`s, because it's existing now
- Delete the random content type

Comment: I need to delete the field comment_body becase field permissions are inherited for all the content types and that is why I created another field and deleted this one

Comment: You can turn off required option on the field comment_body and hide via css.
Another solution https://www.drupal.org/node/1038652#comment-10968421

Comment: I tried to do the same but with 'author' and 'subject' fields but non of them are in the 'Select an existing field' list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a patch which actually needs review in Drupal Core concerning this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2717717

I applied it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

First delete that field and clean Drupal's Cache, if that doesn't work just try to use this patch:

https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/1038652-comment-body-field-95-test-and-fix-D7.patch

Comment: I need to delete the field comment_body becase field permissions are inherited for all the content types and that is why I created another field and deleted this one

Answer (score 0):

I recovered comments with recreating the tables (take care: **all the comments will be removed**):

- comment,
- field_data_comment_body,
- field_revision_comment_body;

and reset statistics with:

```
UPDATE node_comment_statistics SET comment_count = 0;
```

Where to get SQL query to recreate them? Get it from another Drupal installation *with* comments.